# how does grubx64.efi locate its grub.cfg file?

Tags: grub2

I try to understand how Ubuntu's grubx64.efi find the three-command (search, set, configfile) grub.cfg which points to the menu-creating grub.cfg.

I have grubx64.efi both on my internal and an external drive. These two files have the same md5sum value, so they are absolutely identical.

I've read on several occasions that the location of this three-command grub.cfg is included into the grubx64.efi file. However booting with one or the other of the grubx64.efi files does not produce the same grub menu. So obviously my two grubx64.efi files do not use the same grub.cfg, whose location cannot then be in those grubx64.efi files.

Does grubx64.efi retrieve its own location by itself (I did not find any grub command to allow that), and interprets the grub.cfg file which is in the same directory,
or does it retrieve this location from the efi's nvram,
or does it retrieve it from any other mean ?

---

Thank you to both of you who provided comments and responses. However you did not inform me for anything I already know.

I think you misunderstood my question. In the last paragraph I wrote :

"Does grubx64.efi retrieve its own location by itself (I did not find any grub command to allow that), and interprets the grub.cfg file which is in the same directory, or does it retrieve this location from the efi's nvram, or does it retrieve it from any other mean ?"

It turns out that I perfectly know that a grub.cfg file lays in the same directory as grubx64.efi. In other words, the question is :

how does grubx64.efi locate this very directory ?

grubx64.efi does not know from its own which is this directory.